# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1) any idea?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, iis

All of a sudden, out of nowhere, I get this response from my web service hosted locally

> Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
> error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' could not be opened -- 'Unknown error (8013141e)'

Everything has been fine and then I get that error without having made any changes to any configuration or anything.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
> error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' could not be opened -- 'Unknown error (8013141e)'

Comment: Does this happen for every request? Have you tried restarting IIS (and using `iis_reset`)? Does the file exist on disk at that path? Can you post the stack trace (and any relevant code)?

Comment: Have you changed permissions lately? Has the application pool identity changed for the web service? It is also possible that `mscorlib.dll` has gotten corrupted (so a reinstallation of .NET 2.0 may be needed).

Comment: @user974725 - The error message is about .NET 2.0 (`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\`). If this is supposed to be a .NET 4.0 web service, you need to make sure the application pool is setup correctly.

Comment: You're right. Well everything was working fine for about a year until yesterday and I've made no changes to anything, I haven't installed any new software or have done anything on my machine but browse the web. No idea how this is happening but it's a very serious problem right now for me.

Comment: I tried installing .NET 2.0 again and get Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0009: Metadata file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll' could not be opened -- 'Unknown error (8013141e)'

Comment: Is there a disk or temp directory running out of space?

Comment: no disk or temp running out of space. still can't find a solution. I tried reinstalling .NET 2.0 too. still no solution = (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual suspects:

- Clear c:\windows\temp
- Clear C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
- Ditto asp.net 4 / Framework64 etc
- Run chkdsk/f
- Check anti virus software / host intrusion detection systems for rule updates (rules preventing executing code from temp folders will break .Net serialization for starters)

  - if running any security software, disable it temporarily and go from there
- Conversely, if you're not running any security software, run one of the free virus scanners (I like [Nod32](http://www.eset.com/home/products/online-scanner/)) to see if anything crept in.
- Was any windows update applied around the time of the break? Check the update history.

Also, check for system restore points. If you just want to get it working and not worry about what happened, you might be able to restore to a point in time before it broke. I'd call that a last resort though!